# How to implement a search function in a geolocation app in javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile, geolocation

I'm new to mobile application and i'm currently working on a geolocation app in javascript. I need to implement a search box where the user enters the name of a location and the weather data for that location is displayed. If the location does not exist, the user must be informed accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please include all source code around your applications current implementation of this semantic. We would be happy to analyse it and give the appropriate feedback.